# How to send embedded image created using PIL/pillow as email (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am creating image that I would like to embed in the e-mail. I cannot figure out how to create image as binary and pass into MIMEImage. Below is the code I have and I have error when I try to read image object - the error is "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'".

```
image=Image.new("RGBA",(300,400),(255,255,255))
image_base=ImageDraw.Draw(image)
emailed_password_pic=image_base.text((150,200),emailed_password,(0,0,0))
imgObj=emailed_password_pic.read()
msg=MIMEMultipart()
html="""<p>Please finish registration <br/><img src="cid:image.jpg"></p>"""
img_file='image.jpg'
msgText = MIMEText(html,'html')
msgImg=MIMEImage(imgObj)
msgImg.add_header('Content-ID',img_file)
msg.attach(msgImg)
msg.attach(msgText)
```

If you look at line 4 - I am trying to read image so that I can pass it into MIMEImage. Apparently, image needs to be read as binary. However, I don't know how to convert it to binary so that .read() can process it.

**FOLLOW-UP**
I edited code per suggestions from jsbueno - thank you very much!!!:

```
  emailed_password=os.urandom(16)
  image=Image.new("RGBA",(300,400),(255,255,255))
  image_base=ImageDraw.Draw(image)
  emailed_password_pic=image_base.text((150,200),emailed_password,(0,0,0))
  stream_bytes=BytesIO()
  image.save(stream_bytes,format='png')
  stream_bytes.seek(0)
  #in_memory_file=stream_bytes.getvalue()
  #imgObj=in_memory_file.read()
  imgObj=stream_bytes.read()
  msg=MIMEMultipart()
  sender='xxx@abc.com'
  receiver='jjjj@gmail.com'
  subject_header='Please use code provided in this e-mail to confirm your subscription.'
  msg["To"]=receiver
  msg["From"]=sender
  msg["Subject"]=subject_header
  html="""<p>Please finish registration by loging into your account and typing in code from this e-mail.<br/><img src="cid:image.png"></p>"""
  img_file='image.png'
  msgText=MIMEText(html,'html')
  msgImg=MIMEImage(imgObj) #Is mistake here?
  msgImg.add_header('Content-ID',img_file)
  msg.attach(msgImg)
  msg.attach(msgText)
  smtpObj=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.mandrillapp.com', 587)
  smtpObj.login(userName,userPassword)
  smtpObj.sendmail(sender,receiver,msg.as_string())
```

I am not getting errors now but e-mail does not have image in it. I am confused about the way image gets attached and related to in html/email part. Any help is appreciated!

**UPDATE:
This code actually works - I just had minor typo in the code on my PC.**

Comment: Forgot - I am using Python 3.4

Comment: I am importing the following modules:

Comment: from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

Comment: If you have information to add to your question, please [edit] it instead of posting comments.

Comment: Is the image arriving as an attachment?

Comment: No, no attachment arrives. It seems image gets "lost" in the process, i.e. it gets created since I don't get any errors but it does not get attached.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of conceptual errors there, both in using PIL and on what format an image should be in order to be incorporated into an e-mail.

In PIL: the ImageDraw class operates inplace, not like the Image class calls, which usually return a new image after each operation. In your code, it means that the call to `image_base.text` is actually changing the pixel data of the object that lies in your `image` variable. This call actually returns `None`  and the code above should raise an error like "AttributeError: None object does not have attribute 'read'"  on the following line.

Past that (that is, you should fetch the data from your `image` variable to attach it to the e-mail) comes the second issue: PIL, for obvious reasons, have images in an uncompressed, raw pixel data format in memory. When attaching images in e-mails we usually want images neatly packaged inside a file - PNG or JPG formats are usually better depending on the intent - let's just stay with .PNG. So, you have to create the file data using PIL, and them attach the file data (i.e. the data comprising a PNG file, including headers, metadata, and the actual pixel data in a compressed form). Otherwise you'd be putting in your e-mail a bunch of (uncompressed) pixel data that the receiving party would have no way to assemble back into an image (even if he would treat the data as pixels, raw pixel data does not contain the image shape so-)

You have two options: either generate the file-bytes in memory, or write them to an actual file in disk, and re-read that file for attaching. The second form is easier to follow. The first is both more efficient and "the right thing to do" - so let's keep it:

```
from io import BytesIO
# In Python 2.x:
# from StringIO import StringIO.StringIO as BytesIO

image=Image.new("RGBA",(300,400),(255,255,255))
image_base=ImageDraw.Draw(image)
# this actually modifies "image"
emailed_password_pic=image_base.text((150,200),emailed_password,(0,0,0))
stream = BytesIO()
image.save(stream, format="png")
stream.seek(0)
imgObj=stream.read()
...
```

(NB: I have not checked the part dealing with mail and mime proper in your code - if you are using it correctly, it should work now)

Comment: Thank you for response! Why do I need .seek(0) - could you please explain? I am also confused about where file is saved - in memory? and what's the object that contains the picture that can be attached to e-mail?

Comment: The BytesIO objetc simulates a file in Python, but exists only in memory. After PIL record the information equivalent to a image file in the BytesIO objet, the "seek(0)" rewinds it, so that the subsequent "read" reads the bytes as they would be in a .png file on the filessystem. And like in your original code, that bytestring is in the "imgObj" variable, which you attach to the e-mail.